# How can I make a route "{controller}/{action}/paramname/paramvalue/..." that applies to all my controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

As the title states, I'd like my MVC sites to have an URL pattern like

```
/Products/Category/Books/Sku/123456
```

Where every other url segment is /name/value of the parameter name and its value.

How can I do this?

Comment: Case-sensitive or case-insensitive?

Comment: @Radek S- Case-insensitive please

Comment: do you have only one route in global.asax?

Comment: @Radek S, routing is case insensitive

Comment: what does your Controller Action signature look like for the demo pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASP.NET routing allows to define *catchall* parameters at the end of route mask:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CategoryWithParameters", 
    "Products/Category/{category}/{*parameters}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
);
```

So this Home controller method

```
public ActionResult Index(string category, string parameters)
{
    // slashes were ignored by routing system
    string[] parts = parameters.Split('/');

    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // we want only keys with values 
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length / 2 * 2; i += 2)
        values[parts[i]] = parts[i + 1];

    ViewBag.category = category;
    ViewBag.parameters = parameters;
    ViewBag.values = values;

    return View();
}
```

and this view

```
<p>
@ObjectInfo.Print(ViewBag.category)
</p>
<p>
@ObjectInfo.Print(ViewBag.parameters)
</p>
<p>
@ObjectInfo.Print(ViewBag.values)
</p>
```

render URL h**p://localhost:32690/Products/Category/Books/Sku/123456/Bro/098765/df/34 to

[image: rendered view]